How to using the generated token to authenticate the ADF REST API
Just as my post ticket:
Authenticating to Azure application with JMeter
Now, I could generate the token from the Response body:

But when using the same way to test with ADF REST API
directly:
Pipelines - Get

I got the error message:

{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication
failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}

So, My question is how can I using the generated token to invoke the ADF REST API?

You have a typo in your screenshot - resouorce

@10p, Thanks, I have updated it, but still get the same error.

I have resolved this question by set the token as property by BeanShell Assertion, then using it by HTTP Header Manager in second thread:
${__setProperty(access_token, ${access_token})};


Then, use ${__property(access_token)} in the second thread to get it:


You need to add request after parser for parse token response and than when send second request add preprocessor(or header something) add your parsed token
